# How to read hrm polar files into R

Tags: r

Is there any way to read a hrm file ([hrm file](https://www.file-extension.info/format/hrm)) into R without ending in a super messy dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I finally have found the answer in the description of the [RHRV package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RHRV/RHRV.pdf):

```
library(RHRV) # loading RHRV package

hr.data <- CreateHRVData()
hr.data <- SetVerbose(hr.data, TRUE)
hr.data <- LoadBeatPolar(hr.data, "filepath/filename.hrm")
```